# Things in controller doesn't appear using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I am trying to show silder using ng-repeat. But picture and other things in controller don't appear.
Here is my js code

```js
angular.module('starter', [])
.controller('slider', function($scope) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
    });
     $scope.pictures=[
  {
    img:"http://www.brics-info.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Transmission-Lines.jpg,
    info:"Эрчим хүчний барилга угсралт",
    desc:"Засвар, тестчилэл"
  },
  {
    img:"http://www.burns-group.com/images/uploads/projects/Amtrak-Zoo-Transmission-Line-3.jpg",
    info:"Эрчим хүчний барилга угсралт",
    desc:"Засвар, тестчилэл"
  },
  {
    img:"http://www.sgceng.com/snp_lib/showpic.php?recordID=630&timestamp=1204139644&table=sgcengco",
    info:"Эрчим хүчний барилга угсралт",
    desc:"Засвар, тестчилэл"
  }
  ] ;
})
```

```html
This is index.html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
          
<div class="slider" ng-app="starter" ng-controller="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li ng-repeat="picture in pictures">
        <img ng-src="{{picture.img}}"> <!-- image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3 class="black-text">{{picture.info}}</h3>
          <h5 class="blue blue-text text-lighten-4">{{picture.desc}}</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--slider-->
```

why it doesn't appear?

Comment: Can you access controller data from UI?

Comment: where have you instantiated the controller?? ng-controller?

Comment: ng-app="starter" ng-controller="slider" add this in your body tag

Comment: @Diljohn5741 In body, I wrote ng-app, and i used ui-router to add controller

Comment: what it shows on page if you try {{pictures}} before ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include controller in your *index.html* page. and use **ng-app="moduleName"** and use **ng-controller="yourController"**. say script.js your controller file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app='starter'> /* used your module name as ng-app name */

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script> /* load your controller file */
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="slider"> /* use your controller  */
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">{{pictures}}
      <li ng-repeat="picture in pictures">
        <img ng-src="{{picture.img}}"> <!-- image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3 class="black-text">{{picture.info}}</h3>
          <h5 class="blue blue-text text-lighten-4">{{picture.desc}}</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

[PLUNKER Demo Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/zTfIjUaN3zUP9bcjMLjW?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much. it's working only one page.I'm using angular-ui-router   How can I load it ? Please check it [Plunker Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/oYR3bFCDEpzSrzLTV7iy?p=preview)

Comment: In your plunker demo has dependency injection problem  remove `'starter.controller'` from module dependency like:  `var app=angular.module('starter', ['ui.router'])`. then should work

Comment: Also `$('.slider').slider({full_width: true});` use in `$timeout` .See my updated  PLUNKER demo